# How to include the gem gon in a haml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In need to put this into my .html.erb file to use gon:

```
<%= include_gon %>
```

Now what do I put into my .html.haml file that is the equivalent to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by,

```
 = include_gon
```

Comment: Could have thought of that myself... time to end the day with a beer! Thanks